# Finding attributes near route (linestring)

Tags: python, django, postgis, geodjango

Basically, I want to know if there is a way to query all objects with a geographic field that are near a linestring in django using postgis. I am calculating a route and want to find objects that are approximately on that route (say max distance from the linestring 2m - 10m). I cannot find a way online that seems to solve this.

I can, of course, create an interval around the route of say 2m, and then create a polygon using these intervals and check which points fall within this created surface, but I wonder if there is a more direct approach (the way I described above).

This is some psu-code for my first described method (this i want)

```py
def get_objects_on_route():
    Model.objects.filter(geo_location__some_lookup=all_points_in_route_route, max_distance=2m)
```

other method which I could implement

```py
def get_objects_on_route():
points_in_surface = []
for each element in route:
    points_in_surface.append(two_corrected_points)
poly= Polygon(all_points_on_route)
Model.objects.filter(geo_location__covered_by=poly)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, you can easily make this kind of query using Django's PostGIS filtering by creating a [`LineString`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/gis/geos/#linestring) object instead of a [`Point`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/gis/geos/#django.contrib.gis.geos.Point).

```py
from django.contrib.gis.geos import LineString

line = LineString(*coords_in_route)
Model.object.filter(geo_location__distance_lte=(line, D(m=2)))
```

I tested it and seems to be working correctly:

[image: map with points along a route highlighred]